# Notification runs then immediately crashes

Tags: java, android

I have proximity alerts set up. (ADDED CRASH LOG)

When the proximity alert fires, I want a notification to load. Then when the user clicks the notification, a new activity/form should load.

Right now, the notification runs then the app crashes.  The notification text is received and displayed successfully though.

Does anyone see something wrong with my code that would cause it to crash when firing the notification?

**This code sets up the proximity alert/notification**

```
    public void SetupProximityAlerts(LocationManager lm, String name, String info, double latitude, double longitude, int range)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra("Name", name);
    intent.putExtra("Info", info);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, range, -1, pi);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

    registerReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(), filter);
}
```

**And here is my BroadcastReceiver which sets the data to display in the notification.  The app crashes when running: nm.notify(0, n);**

Everything up until nm.notify(0, n); runs successfully. I've verified this with logging.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String deal = (String) extras.get("Info");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ViewTarget.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Resources res = context.getResources();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon)).setTicker(deal).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Message")
            .setContentText(deal);
    Notification n = builder.getNotification();

    n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    nm.notify(0, n);
}
}
```

**And here is the activity I want to load when the user clicks the notification**

```
public class ViewTarget extends ListActivity
{

@Override
public ListAdapter getListAdapter()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getListAdapter();
}

@Override
public ListView getListView()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getListView();
}

@Override
public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setListAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locations);
    Log.v("db", "Inside ViewTarget");
}

}
```

Here is the crash log

```
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.kjdv.gpsVegas.MyBroadcastReceiver (has extras) } in com.kjdv.gpsVegas.MyBroadcastReceiver@44a4bc30
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:905)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:110)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:90)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at com.kjdv.gpsVegas.MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(MyBroadcastReceiver.java:51)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:892)
04-17 21:53:52.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4717):     ... 9 more
```

Thanks!
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission`

Did you forget a permission?

Comment: I will add this permission, but the notifications previously worked with the same permissions i have now.  I sort of broke the code trying to add the functionality which loads an activity after the notification click.

Comment: Well, that fixed the crash problem.  Shouldn't have spoke so soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
```

the above line in your crash indicate that you are using vibrate functionality then youmust add permission in manifeast file.The below is the permission needed to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```